# how to randomize the elements of a array in vhdl code?

Tags: random, vhdl, intel-fpga

I have a table with a known number of elements. I would like to randomize its elements so that each time I display it, its elements are displayed in random order. in vhdl using Fpga stratix3

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It is expected that question-askers show some work and ask specific questions, eg "How can I generate a random number in VHDL?" (which almost certainly has been asked already and so there will be an answer). Anyway, you don't give enough information for anyone to answer your question, eg: Is this for hardware? Or for your testbench?

Comment: To get you started:
semi random values can be created with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear-feedback_shift_register

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no easy VHDL langage solution to generate random numbers on hardware.
To generate a pseudo random number, you can use a LFSR. See for example:
[Pseudo Random Number Generator using LFSR in VHDL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43081067/pseudo-random-number-generator-using-lfsr-in-vhdl)

To generate a true random number, you must create a ring oscillator random number generator.
See for example:
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/81843/ring-oscillator-true-random-number-generator-trng-vs-physically-unclonable-fu

For simulation there is built-in support for random numbers in VHDL. See for example:
[Generating random integer in vhdl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53353363/generating-random-integer-in-vhdl)

You can then use the generated random numbers to randomize your array.